# XCODE : Multiple Target

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

In my project i have added multiple projects for different environments like QA, Stage, Production, UAT. Will it has any impact on app size. Any drawbacks about having multiple targets in my project. Appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the purpose of different targets in your case? Do you point to different web services base URL during production or QA? Do you have different icons for different phases?

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't affect the app size, since when archiving the app you archive only one target. Unless, of course, the have dependencies between them, which shouldn't be the case if they are for different environments.